# Why does most of autorun actions doesn't work in windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, usb, autorun

Note: this is only for educational purposes.

Basically I have created a simple autorun.inf file and placed it in my USB Drive with below options:

```
[AUTORUN]
OPEN=file.bat
SHELLEXECUTE=file.bat
ICON=red.ico
LABEL=My CD-ROM
USEAUTOPLAY=0
SHELL=ReadMe
SHELL\ReadMe=View README File
SHELL\ReadMe\Command=notepad.exe README.TXT
```

The only options I could see working are `ICON` and `LABEL` and nothing else, even though I have added `SHELL` option, but cant see no option for `readme` while I right click on the USB drive. nor does the `OPEN`/`SHEELEXECUTE` open the `file.bat` which is placed in the same location as `autorun.inf`.

is it microsoft that have disabled it for security reasons? or am I missing something?

Comment: Is Autorun enabled on the computer? Do other Autorun.inf work?

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I believe so, I mean `icon` and `label` options work.

Comment: No, I mean the auto-executing functionality. Have you tried it with an autorun.inf not created by you?

Comment: "No, I mean the auto-executing functionality. " Its disabled to prevent malware infections, has been since Windows 7 sp1.

Answer (score 1):

Autorun was disabled by default in Windows 7 and remained so in subsequent versions due to the security issues that "feature" presented. In 2011 Microsoft estimated that fully 50% of virus infections took advantage of the autorun function in some way, so such a decision was a no-brainer to them.

This is why autorun is disabled mostly disabled in current versions of Windows.